# Superset map.gl not working for personal data

Tags: apache-superset

I have just setup superset and linked it to my database.  I've signed up for a mapbox license and using the api key can get a basic map to appear.  However the map.gl is not showing my data.  I've confirmed that its working in the example dataset. [image: My chart configuration]. [image: superset's example chart.]
It seems to only happen on mapbox grid.  the heatmap is working fine.
What am I missing here?